# how to list all the internet's IP ranges?

Tags: command-line, scripting, ip, www

I was wondering if I list all the IP ranges directly available on the internet. perhaps also group them by country and ISP?

I know that a lot of people do research nowadays on datamining and semantic-web, etc. I hoping to discover an elegant way that exists for achieving this.

Comment: How does this question relate to Unix/Linux?

Comment: @ChrisDown: It's a good question, even if it is off-topic. To where can it be migrated?

Comment: @ChrisDown for Server Administration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a geo-IP database. [Maxmind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) makes one available.

If you're using Debian you can install `geoip-database` and `geoip-bin` to get the database and command line querying utilities.

There are libraries available in several languages:

- `libgeo-ip-perl`
- `php5-geoip`
- `python-geoip`
- `tclgeoip`

As well as an Apache module:

- `libapache2-mod-geoip`

---

Based on your comment, here's some explanation:

IP addresses are globally organized by IANA. IANA distributes blocks of addresses to **Regional Internet Registries** (e.g., ARIN, RIPE, etc.). The RIR delegates block of addresses to **Local Internet Registries** (organizations) or **National Internet Registries** (nations).

So every IP can be correlated to a specific country at the most basic. When an address block is registered the registering entity is required to list a physical address. In many/most cases this brings it to within a metropolitan area. This is public data, and is probably accurate enough to scare the bejezuz out of a not insignificant portion of the population.

Going further, Maxmind most likely aggregates usage data from various places. I don't have any specific knowledge of Maxmind's business practices, but the following are various ways locating a specific IP is possible:

- Usage and traffic that volunteers the address (always ship to the same physical address, always get directions to/from the same physical address).
- Wardriving (Google has done a lot of this, as well as Skyhook).
- Cable/DSL providers obviously know the exact location of each IP they assign and can probably be persuaded to share that information to within say a mile for the right price.

Etc..

IP addresses don't generally change location much (if ever). New IPs are added to the list all the time (at least until we run out of them) but generally, well established IPs aren't going to move to a new city or state. So the longer it's been in the database the more reliable the estimated location is.

Comment: Thanks bahamat, but I am more interested in knowing how Maxmind implemented their service more than using their service..